# How to get product stock status on the listing page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, inventory, stock-status, stock-availability

I am using Magento 2.3.1

I want to display stock status on the listing page. So, how can I get "Stock Status" attribute value on the listing page?

I have tried below code:

```
<?php 
 $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
 foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){

    $stock_status = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('quantity_and_stock_status')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

 } 
?>
```

And tried below as well:

```
<?php 
     $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
     foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){

        $default_stock_status = $_product->getData('quantity_and_stock_status');

     } 
?>
```

But for each scenario, I got "Out of stock" even though the product is in stock
here `quantity_and_stock_status` is the default "Stock Status" attribute.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can try the following code

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
) {
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}
// you can pass $product object to the function
public function getStockStatus($product)
{
    return $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
}
```

**You can get all the stock details by**

```
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
$stockData = $stockItem->getData();
$stockItem->getIsInStock();
```

**Hope it helps.**

Comment: I tried this as well and it only gives the product quantity but I need to display the stock status values e.g. In Stock, Out of Stock.

Comment: you can use `getIsInStock()` method

Comment: to get all the stock details you can use this class `Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface`

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the only simple products in your system then using the `Stock Status` field check then  Product status is Ok.

But when you have a configurable or bundle or group product then it is not a good idea to use the `Stock Status` field to check stock status. Because of these types of product's stock status, it depends on its child Products status.

That is this, use of `$_product->isAvailable() and $_product->isSaleable()` is the best idea.See at https://github.com/devamitbera/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml#L80

Comment: correct! need to check for `$_product->isSaleable()`

Comment: @Amit What exactly do $_product->isAvailable() mean? is it says that products is enabled or disabled?

Comment: use the [magento 2 custom stock status](https://www.mageants.com/custom-stock-status-for-magento-2.html) of mageants it will help to your store

Answer (score 4):

Inject   \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository, in constructor

e.g:

```
protected $_stockItemRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository
)
{
    $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
}
```

Use function to get stock data using product id

```
public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
    }
```

Then you may call in your phtml file

```
$id = YOUR_PRODUCT_ID;
$productStock = $block->getStockItem(1225);
echo $productStock->getQty(); echo '<br />';
echo $productStock->getMinQty(); echo '<br />';
echo $productStock->getMinSaleQty(); echo '<br />';
echo $productStock->getMaxSaleQty(); echo '<br />';
echo $productStock->getIsInStock(); echo '<br />';
```

Source: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-product-stock-quantity-and-other-stock-information/

Answer (score 3):

**Note:- Object Manager is not recommended way.**

> You can inject class in your constructor this way

```
<?php 
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();

     foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){

        $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository');

        $StockState->get($_product->getId());
        echo $StockState->getIsInStock();

     } 
?>
```